# How to insert image above footer and remain still [WORDPRESS]?

Tags: html, wordpress, css, wordpress-theming

I want to add a picture above the footer as seen picture below, or you can visit the website: http://creativelab.twofour54.com/en/

[Example of the photo from TwoFour54](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MVmnX.png)

The website I'm testing it on is wordpress. I tried playing with the footer.php however it works nicely but when I stretch the site (zoom out or in) It gets ruined. I tried to make it static with position tag from CSS but that didnt work.

```html
<div class="cfa" style="margin-left: 200px; width: 100%; z-index: 10;">
 <div class="container">
  <div class="col-sm-12">
   <img src="http://localhost:8080/TESTWORDPRESS/wp-content/uploads/2017/01/Sketch-Book-icon.png">
  </div>
 </div>
</div> 

<?php 
 /*
 Template for Footer
 */
 ?>

  <footer id="footer">
   <div class="row clearfix">
             
                <?php 
    
    if ( ! dynamic_sidebar ( 'footer_widgets' ) ){
     thdglkr_emptysidebar('Footer');
     }            
    ?>

   </div><!-- row -->
   
            <?php if (_option('footer_menu','1')=='1'){ ?>
   <div class="footer-last row mtf clearfix">
    <span class="copyright"><?php echo _option('footer_text'); ?></span>
                <?php 
    wp_nav_menu(  
     array(  
      'theme_location' => 'secondary',
      'menu' => 'Footer Menu',
      'container'        => 'div',
      'container_class'  => '' ,
      'menu_class'    => 'foot-menu',
      
     )  
    ); 
   }else{?>
     
   <div class="footer-last row mtf clearfix center">
    <span class="copyright center"><?php echo _option('footer_text'); ?></span> 
                    
   <?php } ?> 


   </div><!-- end last footer -->

  </footer><!-- end footer -->

 </div><!-- end layout -->
 </div><!-- end frame -->


 <?php if (_option('footer_gototop')==1): ?>
  <div id="toTop"><i class="icon-angle-up"></i></div><!-- Back to top -->
 <?php endif; ?>
    



<?php wp_footer(); ?>

 

</body>
</html>
```

note: code above is Footer.php from my test local host

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please post a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). What solutions have you tried?

Comment: I tried to add div tags as seen above in the footer.php (I mean isn't explainable if you understand wordpress structure) and tried to play with it's inner css but that didnt work. since it grows in size when zooming out and in.

Comment: How can I explain it more? Verifiable example, I can't post the whole site, since it is in a localhost\

Comment: Please read the link. You need to include enough code that we can replicate the issue. Where is your CSS? You've included a lot of code, but much of it is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Put your `.cfa` inside your footer in your html. And in your css:

```
.cfa {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
left: 200px; 
margin-top: -100px; //change this to the height of your image
}
```

EDIT: Actually it's better if you can remove it from your HTML and just add it via css using a `:before` pseudo-element if you're using it just for design purposes.